# Questions about tuning browse-to-watch memory

Tags: cobalt

I'm looking at browse-to-watch performance,
I am using image_cache_size_in_bytes = 7MB and remote_typeface_cache_size_in_bytes = 0MB , but the performance of browse-to-watch is lower than that of youtube-certi. (It takes about 6 seconds to 8 seconds.)
So I tuned  image_cache_size_in_bytes = 20MB  and remote_typeface_cache_size_in_bytes = 4MB, which is  fine (it about 2-4 seconds). but this option is not available because our platform current memory environment is not enough.
Is there any way to fix this by fixing the other parts?

Comment: This sounds more like application configuration problem than programming related. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So performance is good but you are short on RAM? How much RAM does your system have? What version of Cobalt do you use?

Comment: thank u for reply, mmotorny. ram is 256MB. The cobalt version is 11.153049.

Comment: I would guess that you'd find the largest improvement by tweaking the value of mozjs_garbage_collection_threshold_in_bytes ( https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/release_11/src/cobalt/doc/performance_tuning.md#garbage-collection-trigger-threshold ).  Feel free to take a look at other options in that guide.  You may also have luck by setting a framerate limit by using 'cobalt_minimum_frame_time_in_milliseconds'.

Comment: Please search tweaks with "browse-to-watch" tag in the document which Andrew referred. Some of them have pros and cons so you might need to do a regression test after making changes.

Comment: 256MB looks very small. How much "free" memory do you have?

Comment: Also, what is your CPU (architecture, cores, frequency)?

Comment: @jihoonjang Soft reminder.